# Insect identification: Fly with eye strip

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, taxonomy

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Location details:
Country - India,

State - Tamil Nadu,

District- Chennai.

Found this fly in my backyard keen to know its exact name. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide your geographic location. Thanks.

Comment: The antenna seen here is not that of _Scathophaga_ (which would have a strong bristle at the front base of the last segment); I'm thinking _Tabanidae_, but not knowing where the photo was taken _IS_ a huge handicap (from the OP's handle, perhaps Indian subcontinent?).  Another photograph showing the rear end of the critter _would_ be nice as well (but probably impossible; I'm sure the animal is no longer available).

Comment: @ArthurJFrost side view & additional pics added.

Comment: @Charles location details added.

Comment: @Ναείστεαισιόδοξοι The large space between their two eyes doesn't match up with fly you mentioned and any link can be provided will be useful to confirm this species.

Comment: Looking at the bottom photo the way the wings are held and the spines coming off the scutellum (the white plate just before the wings) now suggests to me the family _Stratiomyidae_ (Soldier Flies); having no detailed knowledge of the Indian fauna of that family forbids me from speculating further.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely Stratiomyidae, probably genus Odontomyia. Very widespread and species-rich genus.
Here is an example of Odontomyia - not the same species - https://www.flickr.com/photos/63075200@N07/sets/72157632905103705/.

Comment: Can you add a source, an image and explanation why you think this is correct? As if now it's just a comment really.